# Visibility of JFrame by adding JPanel in Netbean

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have two classes: one is JFrame and second is JPanel. When i add JPanel object in JFrame class it makes not error but did not show JPanel result. It only shows blank JFrame.
This is my JPanel class:

```
public class grafix extends JPanel {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponents(g);
        Graphics2D g2= (Graphics2D) g;
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(15,10,200,300);
        g2.draw(r);
        g2.setColor(Color.blue);
        g2.fillOval(50, 50, 30,30);
        g2.drawString("Hello World", 120, 50);
    }
}
```

And this is my JFrame Class:

```
public class JFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public JFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                grafix gf = new grafix(); // object created of JPanel class
                frame.getContentPane().add(gf);// by adding object
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

No error being mentioned in Netbean but it did not show any drawing but frame only.

Comment: 1) Don't use `JFrame` as a class name 2) No need to extend `javax.swing.JFrame` just create an instance & use

Comment: but it automaticaly create when i get new frame file in netbean. all require type of inheritence automaticaly defined when we get new file in netbean ide.

Comment: *"but it automaticaly create when i get new frame file in netbean."*  Don't be silly.  Netbeans allows you to change the name to something sensible.  Stop letting the editor treat you as though you were it's slave.  Take command of it, show it that **you** are the boss!

Answer (score 1):

The graphics are shown but your frame is too small to show the panel graphics. Your `Grafix` panel component is using the default preferred size of 0x0 to the frame reveals nothing. Override `getPreferredSize` in the class to allow the correct size to be set when the frame is packed

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(250, 400);
}
```

Comment: Still not working. i think  NetBeans adopt different methadology of coding. this code is properly work in notepade. but in Netbeans it gives no results.

Comment: Eh, Netbeans doesnt change rules about Swing itself works, anyway please post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see what is the problem